# UPDATE, INSERT and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in one query

Tags: mysql, string, sql-update, sql-insert, sql-null

I am new to posting on Stack Overflow, so please bare with me.

Say I have a table called Table1 with the columns order_id and general_notes (and a few others with more data).

I am trying to write a query that 1) INSERT order_id and general_notes INTO my table if order_id does not exist yet 2) CONTACT UPDATE general_notes if column already contains text and 3)UPDATE general_notes column if order_id has been pushed to db already. **Essentially I do not want order_id to be duplicated in my table so if it doesn't exist I want to push both columns, if it already exists without any general_notes added I want to add data and if general_notes does already exist I want to concat new text to the end.**

The script I currently have adds new entry to db and updates the general_notes column if additional notes are added but I can't figure out how to update the general_notes column for an order_id that is already in db aka general_notes is NULL.

This is what I currently have:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table1 (order_id, general_notes) VALUES(:order_id, :general_notes) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE general_notes = CONCAT(general_notes, '. ', :general_notes)";
```

Comment: Show your table schema and part of the code that executes the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [`concat_ws()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws): it gracefully skips `null` values (and does not concatenates the separator to `null`s):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (order_id, general_notes) 
VALUES(:order_id, :general_notes) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    general_notes = CONCAT_WS('. ', general_notes, VALUES(general_notes))
```

Note that you can use `VALUES()` in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause to refer to the value that would have been otherwise inserted.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!